# How to add a secondary axis in fl_chart?

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

I am strongly considering migrating the charts that I built in charts_flutter to fl_chart to support null safety, however I can't find in the documentation if it is possible to handle a secondary axis within a chart, which is possible in charts_flutter.

What I would like to get is the following:

[image: Secondary Axis and Annotations Chart]

Is it possible to have a secondary axis in fl_chart?

Comment: You mean 20%,40% and 100 ,200 scales?

Comment: Yep. For example, y2 axis for green line and y1 axis for blue line

Comment: You have to calculate your own, There are no ways for two y axis